# R markdown! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <recently read> \endtemplate

Tags: r, matrix, latex, r-markdown, knitr

```
\begin{array}{cc} &
\begin{array}{ccc} I & A & D & B & E & C & F
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{ccc}
I \\
A \\
D \\
B \\
E \\
C \\
F \\
\end{array}
&
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
```

Here's the code I wrote to generate a Matrix in R markdown, i successfully made the Matrix that I want. However it is giving error when I try to knit the file into a pdf. Below is the response I received.

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>  \endtemplate

Answer (score 2):

You define all your inner arrays with 3 centred columns, but then you try to use them with anything between only a single column and up to seven columns. The number of columns you specify must match the number of columns you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cc} 
&
\begin{array}{ccccccc} 
I & A & D & B & E & C & F
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c}
I \\
A \\
D \\
B \\
E \\
C \\
F \\
\end{array}
&
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
    0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(you could create a similar layout much easier with the `nicematrix` or `tabularray` package - without all this odd nesting of arrays and with much better spacing)